# What is the difference between all night and all the night? Can I use ‘the’ if I am referring the night specifically as last night

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, articles, nouns, spoken-english

people say night is singular and the night is seen as plural and night is usually singular so it should be all night not all the night. What if I want to talk about last night or the listener understands which night I am talking about.

Comment: _The night_ is not plural. _All night_ is a 'set phrase', but _all the night_ is possible, and we say _through[out] the night, during the night_ etc. You can also say _all last night_ or _all that night_.

Answer (score 1):

The noun *night* can be countable or uncountable depending on the context. Usually the plural form of it will still be *night*, but you can also use *nights* when describing a collection of nights:

- Dealing with sleepless nights is very stressful.

In my opinion, *the night* is also fine if you're referring to a specific night when both you and your audience (or whoever you're speaking to) know which night you're referring to:

- I'll never forget the night we met.